Geometry nodes: problem with intersect boolean of mesh and instances
I`m making a roof generator, and I have a little problem with intersect of meshes:


And there is the result

Here is nodes and geometry:





i cannot see any intersection on your images!? can you please add an image with maybe some annotations where the intersection occurs? thx.

Do you try and add a Realize Instances node between the Instance on Points and Mesh Boolean nodes at the far end of the graph, just before the Group Output node ?

Thx, it helped)

intersection is in bool node

Does the Realize Instances node solve completely your problem ? Or are some issues remaining ? In this case, could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?
